# How to calculate the significance of change between values in the frame of an equal territory over time?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, geostatistics

I do not know much about statistics as you could notice below. 
I need to calculate the significance of change in land cover in two periods of time. The problem is I have two equal by surface territories with different by territory land cover territories so when using two-tail t-test I get p=1: Is it because the change is not significant or do I need to use a different significance test? In the latter case, which test would be most appropriate?

Comment: To make progress, you need to come up with a statistical model of land cover change. This is important because the very strong spatial correlations will cause crucial assumptions of the standard tests (such as the Student t test) to fail. The model, whatever it may be, will suggest an appropriate statistic to measure the change. In the present case, difference of total area is not a good choice, because it effectively allows loss of land cover in one location to cancel gain of land cover in another location. Making a formal statement of your study question would be a good start.